# Как прибавить к дате 1 день?

Tags: php, дата

Я не программист, но занимаюсь одним сайтом как администратор. Потребовалось прибавить к дате 1 день. Мне кажется что это нужно сделать вот тут:

```
$date=substr($order->date,0,10);
```

Не подскажете, как это все прописать?

Формат даты - `datetime 2016-09-02 10:13:54`

Спасибо!

Comment: Думаю, там время в формате `unix`. Если так то нужно прибавить к нему `24*60*60`, что равняется одному дню.

Comment: Простите, не программист, не подскажите как это прописать? Я не владею синтаксисом, к сожалению...

Comment: `$date=substr($order->date,0,10) + 24*60*60;` - но это не точно. по 10 символов вполне себе попадает обычная дата типа `24/11/2017`. В этом случае вам надо будет все-же овладеть синтаксисом и разобраться, как именно у вас формируется и используется дата.

Comment: Непонятно, почему плюсуют вопрос. Это хрестоматийный вариант "непонятна суть вопроса". Автор не имеет представления, в каком формате у него хранится дата, то есть дать ответ в принципе невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо. но... Попробовал - выдало ошибку, причем не написало какую. Скрипт в результате не сработал...

Comment: Формат даты datetime 2016-09-02 10:13:54

Answer (score 1):

Выберите тот вариант, который подходит:

1.

```
$timestamp = time(); // 1545818743

$datePlus = (new DateTime('@' . $timestamp))
    ->modify('1 day')
    ->format(DateTime::ATOM);

var_dump($datePlus);
```

2.

```
$dateString = (new DateTime()) -> format(DateTime::ATOM); // 2018-12-26T02:06:57-08:00

$datePlus = (new DateTime($dateString))
    ->modify('1 day')
    ->format(DateTime::ATOM);

var_dump($datePlus);
```

3.

```
$dateObject = new DateTime(); // object DateTime

$datePlus = $dateObject
    ->modify('1 day')
    ->format(DateTime::ATOM);

var_dump($datePlus);
```

Comment: А можно визуально отделить варианты? :)

Comment: К сожалению, основы теории мне не помогут, я не программист, увы...

Answer (score 0):

Я бы так сделал

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($order->date) + 86400);
```

http://codepad.org/PDBMiX6D

Если в общем случае, можно и strtotime заставить «переводить часы», тут я просто прибавил 86400 секунд (один день) к дате.

```
$date = date(
    'Y-m-d', 
    strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($order->date))
);
```

Тут можно уже и `+5 weeks` написать и что угодно вместо `+1 day`

Answer (score -1):

Заработал вот такой вариант:

```
$date = substr(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($order->date.'1 day')),0,10);
```